# React: Verifying Email from Firebase throws auth/operation-not-allowed Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-allowed)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to perform an email validation by sending an email link using `sendEmailVerification`. I recieve the email on my email which looks something like this:

`http://localhost:3000/signup-success?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=oKyOD4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAAF-XCNUIg&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&lang=en`

I suspect that to verify the email, we need to have a different function than `signInWithEmailLink`?

It redirects to my signup-success page that looks like this:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import auth from '../firebase/firebase_client';
import {
  User,
  isSignInWithEmailLink,
  signInWithEmailLink,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { frontendRoutes } from '../components/constants/frontend-routes';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useAppDispatch } from '../redux/app/hooks';
import { updateNotification } from '../redux/slices/notifications';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function SignupSuccess(): ReactElement {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<User | null>(null);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [emailVerified, setEmailVerified] = React.useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      let email;
      if (user !== null) {
        setUser(user);
        email = user.email;
        console.log('Email = ', email, user.emailVerified);
        if (isSignInWithEmailLink(auth, window.location.href)) {
        }
      } else {
        email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
      }
      if (email) {
        signInWithEmailLink(auth, email, window.location.href)
          .then((result) => {
            const user = result.user.displayName;
            dispatch(
              updateNotification({
                message: `Congrats ${
                  user || 'User'
                }. Your Email has been verified.`,
                status: 'success',
                title: 'Verification Success',
              })
            );
            console.log('Success');
            setEmailVerified(true);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(
              'Error occured while verifying: ' + error.code,
              error.message
            );
            console.log('Error = ', error);
            dispatch(
              updateNotification({
                message: `Verification Failed. Common errors could be invalid email and invalid or expired OTPs.`,
                status: 'error',
                title: 'Verification Failed',
              })
            );
          });
      } else {
        dispatch(
          updateNotification({
            message: 'Verification Failed as no email was provided',
            status: 'error',
            title: 'Verification Failed',
          })
        );
        setTimeout(() => router.push('/'), 3000);
      }
    });
  }, [dispatch, router]);

  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome {user.email}</h1>
        {emailVerified ? (
          <p>
            Congrats, your email has been verified! Please wait for admin
            approval before you could start using Break Free Services. Go Back
            to{' '}
            <Link href={frontendRoutes.LOGIN_FOR_MERCHANT_INDIVIDUAL}>
              Login Page
            </Link>{' '}
          </p>
        ) : (
          <p>Verifying...</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div>Continue to Sign Up First.</div>;
}
```

The providers I have enabled in my firebase are:- `Email Provider` and `Phone Number`. But I still get this error, can someone tell me what's going wrong?

Edit 1:
I just realized the method call I was making was just to sign in with the email and not verify one. Seems like there's no way you can redirect users to your website and then handle the response from there unless you have a custom domain for yourself. In case anyone knows anyway to redirect users to localhost or your website and procceed verification from there, please add it otherwise I would close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you don't need `signInWithEmailLink` function. `auth.onAuthStateChanges` is an old version of using methods in firebase. Try to use `onAuthSateChanges(auth, user => {...})` this function is an Observer which are observing what is going on with user. To sign up with email and password you need `signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)` funtion.

**Sending email verification:**

firebase 9+

```js
import { getAuth, sendEmailVerification } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
```

firebase X<9

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
```

`sugnInWithEmailLink()` function is some kind of sign in function like `signInWithEmailAndPasswird()`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, I very well understand that, all I am interested in to know if there's a firebase function or an api that we can use to perform `verifyEmailfromVerificationLink`. I am able to send verification and it works very well, the problem is that upon clicking I want the user to redirect to my page or change the firebase verification template that shows up

Comment: If you send email to user with verification there is rest api with will verify email for you. Same as like sending email to change password.

Comment: You have templates in firebase project.

Comment: Yeah so when firebase sends the link that triggers that api it lands to a native firebase page. I either want landing to be on my custom page or be able to customize that firebase landing page. Also I am not using firebase project, I am just using it's auth library to perform all these authentications

Comment: You need to read about that on your own i have no time sorry. But this is possible.

Comment: Alright thanks anyways